# How to retry the request n times when an item gets an empty field?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrap a range of webpages but I got holes, sometimes it looks like the website fails to send the html response correctly. This results in the csv output file to have empty lines. How would one do to retry n times the request and the parse when the xpath selector on the  response is empty ? Note that I don't have any HTTP errors.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you could do this with a Custom Retry Middleware, you just need to override the `process_response` method of the current [Retry Middleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py):

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware
from scrapy.utils.response import response_status_message


class CustomRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if request.meta.get('dont_retry', False):
            return response
        if response.status in self.retry_http_codes:
            reason = response_status_message(response.status)
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response

        # this is your check
        if response.status == 200 and response.xpath(spider.retry_xpath):
            return self._retry(request, 'response got xpath "{}"'.format(spider.retry_xpath), spider) or response
        return response
```

Then enable it instead of the default `RetryMiddleware` in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'myproject.middlewarefilepath.CustomRetryMiddleware': 550,
}
```

Now you have a middleware where you can configure the `xpath` to retry inside your spider with the attribute `retry_xpath`:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspidername"

    retry_xpath = '//h2[@class="tadasdop-cat"]'
    ...
```

This won't necessarily retry when your Item's field is empty, but you can specify the same path of that field in this `retry_xpath` attribute to make it work.

Comment: Could you explain to me what is `self._retry`, where is the test that checks whether the xpath is empty and also why I don't have to give `process_response` the name of my spider for its third argument ? Thanks

Comment: Check how to create your own [downloader middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#downloader-middleware). About the _retry and the other class methods, remember that we are inheriting from the RetryMiddleware, so we are just overriding its methods (link in the answer). About the spider argument, that's the current spider instance, no need for name.

Comment: Okay thanks. Btw I replaced `if response.status == 200 and response.xpath(spider.retry_xpath)` with `if len(response.xpath(spider.retry_xpath))==0` any reason why you didn't do that instead ?

Answer (score 11):

You can set `RETRY_TIMES` setting in `settings.py` to the amount of times you wish the pages are retried. It defaults to 2 times.

See [more on RetryMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry)

Comment: Strangely if RETRY_TIMES is set to 0, it is still going to retry once. I tried all the time with setting it to 1, but then it will retry it twice.

Comment: @chainstair You can try just to disable retry middleware with `RETRY_ENABLED = False` setting, see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry

Comment: I've tried this, but then I had the problem that it didn't even retry it once. Strange ...