# Why is scrapy suddenly giving me an *unpredictable* AttributeError, stating no attribute 'css'

Tags: scrapy

For my job, I built a scrapy spider to quickly check in on ~200-500 website landing pages for clues that the pages are not functioning, outside of just 400-style errors. (e.g. check for the presence of "out of stock" on page.) This check happens across approx. 30 different websites under my purview, all of them using the same page structure.

This has worked fine, every day, for 4 months.

Then, suddenly, and without change to the code, I started getting unpredictable errors, about 4 weeks ago:

> url_title = response.css("title::text").extract_first()
>   AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'

If I run this spider, this error will occur with, say... 3 out of 400 pages.
Then, if immediately run the spider again, those same 3 pages are scraped just fine without error, and 4 totally different pages will return the same error.

Furthermore, if I run the *EXACT* same spider as below, but replace mapping with just these 7 erroneous landing pages, they are scraped perfectly fine.

Is there something in my code that's not quite right??

I'm going to attach the whole code - sorry in advance!! - I just fear that something I might deem as superfluous may in fact be the cause. So this is the whole thing, but with sensitive data replaced with ####.

I've checked all of the affected pages, and of course the css is valid, and the title is always present.

I've done sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get dist-upgrade on the server running scrapy, in hopes that this would help. No luck.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from w3lib.url import safe_download_url
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_, not_


import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://######:######@localhost/LandingPages', pool_recycle=3600, echo=False)
#conn = engine.connect()

from LandingPageVerifier.models import LandingPagesFacebook, LandingPagesGoogle, LandingPagesSimplifi, LandingPagesScrapeLog, LandingPagesScrapeResults

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# thisyear = datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
# thismonth = datetime.now().strftime("%m")
# thisday = datetime.now().strftime("%d")
# start = date(year=2019,month=04,day=09)

todays_datetime = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, datetime.today().day)
print todays_datetime

landingpages_today_fb = session.query(LandingPagesFacebook).filter(LandingPagesFacebook.created_on >= todays_datetime).all()
landingpages_today_google = session.query(LandingPagesGoogle).filter(LandingPagesGoogle.created_on >= todays_datetime).all()
landingpages_today_simplifi = session.query(LandingPagesSimplifi).filter(LandingPagesSimplifi.created_on >= todays_datetime).all()

session.close()
#Mix 'em together!
landingpages_today = landingpages_today_fb + landingpages_today_google + landingpages_today_simplifi
#landingpages_today = landingpages_today_fb

#Do some iterating and formatting work
landingpages_today = [(u.ad_url_full, u.client_id) for u in landingpages_today]
#print landingpages_today

landingpages_today = list(set(landingpages_today))

#print 'Unique pages: '
#print landingpages_today
# unique_landingpages = [(u[0]) for u in landingpages_today]
# unique_landingpage_client = [(u[1]) for u in landingpages_today]
# print 'Pages----->', len(unique_landingpages)

class LandingPage004Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='LandingPage004Spider'

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(LandingPage004Spider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        #crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        #stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats() 
        stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count'),
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        logitem = LandingPagesScrapeLog(scrape_count = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count'),
                                        is200 = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/200'),
                                        is400 = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/400'),
                                        is403 = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/403'),
                                        is404 = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/404'),
                                        is500 = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/500'),
                                        scrapy_errors = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('log_count/ERROR'),
                                        scrapy_criticals = spider.crawler.stats.get_value('log_count/CRITICAL'),
                                        )
        session.add(logitem)
        session.commit()
        session.close()



    #mapping = landingpages_today
    handle_httpstatus_list = [200, 302, 404, 400, 500]

    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        for url, client_id in self.mapping:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'client_id': client_id})


    def parse(self, response):

        ##DEBUG - return all scraped data
        #wholepage = response.body.lower()

        url = response.url
        if 'redirect_urls' in response.request.meta:
            redirecturl = response.request.meta['redirect_urls'][0]
            if 'utm.pag.ca' in redirecturl:
                url_shortener = response.request.meta['redirect_urls'][0]
            else:
                url_shortener = 'None'
        else:
            url_shortener = 'None'

        client_id = response.meta['client_id']
        url_title = response.css("title::text").extract_first()
        # pagesize = len(response.xpath('//*[not(descendant-or-self::script)]'))
        pagesize = len(response.body)
        HTTP_code = response.status

        ####ERROR CHECK: Small page size
        if 'instapage' in response.body.lower():
            if pagesize <= 20000:
                err_small = 1
            else:
                err_small = 0
        else:
            if pagesize <= 35000:
                err_small = 1
            else:
                err_small = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page contains the phrase 'not found'
        if 'not found' in response.xpath('//*[not(descendant-or-self::script)]').extract_first().lower():
            #their sites are full of HTML errors, making scrapy unable to notice what is and is not inside a script element
            if 'dealerinspire' in response.body.lower():
                err_has_not_found = 0
            else:
                err_has_not_found = 1
        else:
            err_has_not_found = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page cotains the phrase 'can't be found'
        if "can't be found" in response.xpath('//*[not(self::script)]').extract_first().lower():
            err_has_cantbefound = 1
        else:
            err_has_cantbefound = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page contains the phrase 'unable to locate'
        if 'unable to locate' in response.body.lower():
            err_has_unabletolocate = 1
        else:
            err_has_unabletolocate = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page contains phrase 'no longer available'
        if 'no longer available' in response.body.lower():
            err_has_nolongeravailable = 1
        else:
            err_has_nolongeravailable = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page contains phrase 'no service specials'
        if 'no service specials' in response.body.lower():
            err_has_noservicespecials = 1
        else:
            err_has_noservicespecials = 0

        ####ERROR CHECK: Page contains phrase 'Sorry, no' to match zero inventory for a search, which normally says "Sorry, no items matching your request were found."
        if 'sorry, no ' in response.body.lower():
            err_has_sorryno = 1
        else:
            err_has_sorryno = 0

        yield {'client_id': client_id, 'url': url, 'url_shortener': url_shortener, 'url_title': url_title, "pagesize": pagesize, "HTTP_code": HTTP_code, "err_small": err_small, 'err_has_not_found': err_has_not_found, 'err_has_cantbefound': err_has_cantbefound, 'err_has_unabletolocate': err_has_unabletolocate, 'err_has_nolongeravailable': err_has_nolongeravailable, 'err_has_noservicespecials': err_has_noservicespecials, 'err_has_sorryno': err_has_sorryno}



#E-mail settings

def sendmail(recipients,subject,body):

            fromaddr = "#######"
            toaddr = recipients
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = fromaddr
            msg['Subject'] = subject 

            body = body
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

            server = smtplib.SMTP('########)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(fromaddr, "##########")
            text = msg.as_string()
            server.sendmail(fromaddr, recipients, text)
            server.quit()
`
```

Expected results is a perfect scrape, with no errors.
Actual results are unpredicatable AttributeErrors, claiming that attribute 'css' can't be found on some pages. But if I scrape those pages individually, using the same script, they scrape just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're not being throttled by any of these services? They're known to rate limit certain bots and display an alternate page in those cases - such as a captcha or deny entry. Output the response from the service and the HTTP response code when you get the AttributeError thrown and you should be able to debug it one step further.

Comment: HI MatsLindh. It's possible, yes. 
This scraper runs only once daily, and checks perhaps 1-30 pages on any given site, within one minute.
I know for certain that there are no CAPTCHAs. But there could certainly be some throttling. 
Is there a way to tell scrapy to pause between scrapes? I don't care if the scraper takes a long time to run, since it's just once daily. Hmm.... thanks for this. You've got me thinking.

Comment: But then again, if I *immediately* run the spider again, those previously erroneous pages come through just fine, amidst the other 1-29 pages from that site that also come through fine. :/

Comment: Appending the code to include 'download_delay = 5' , to create a 5-second delay between scrapes, still resulted in 3 errors. :(

Comment: As mentioned; output the actual error and HTTP error code when it happens - that should tell you why the lookup fails.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. There is no HTTP error. It's a perfect 200. It finds the page just fine, it just somehow won't pick up on the response.css part of it.

Comment: ....Let alone any of response

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Scrapy can't parse HTML because of markup errors, that's why you can't call `response.css()`. You can catch these events in your code and analyze broken HTML:

```
def parse(self, response):

    try:
     ....
     your code
     .....
    except:
        with open("Error.htm", "w") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

**UPDATE** You can try to check for empty response:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if not response.body:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, meta={'client_id': response.meta["client_id"]})

    # your original code
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
Above the f.write line, I added a line.... print 'whiterabbitobject'. 
With this in place, scrapy finishes without errors. But there are 3-7 occurrences of 'whiterabbitobject'. on the following line however, there is absolutely no sign of response.body. Odd, no?? Hmmm....  Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: With code above you will not have Scrapy errors. Did you check `Error.htm` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that point. When I do this operation with your added code, it does indeed create an Error.htm file. But it's a 0-byte file, following this operation. :(

Comment: That's why you have errors trying to `response.css()` it. You can catch this and send  request again.

Comment: Gosh, I'm so sorry, I can tell you're trying to help me, but I think I'm missing some fundamental knowledge. Can you guide me a little bit further?  You say "You can catch this and send request again."  To do that, should I literally copy all of the "try:" and paste to "except:", which will give the scrape one more chance to send the request again? 
That does seem to work when I try it! :) But it's a lot of duplicated code. 

Or is there something I can add to the code here, to tell the spider to keep trying until it gets a response (because it *will*, if it tries again)? Thanks again.

Comment: Things I've tried with no success:
- Doing the above try/except, with the content of try and except being the exact same
- Commenting out DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'s3': None} in settings.py
- Setting RETRY_TIMES = 5 in settings.py
- Setting DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5 in settings.py
- Adding 'if len(response.xpath(spider.retry_xpath))==0 coding as mentioned in a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404281/how-to-retry-the-request-n-times-when-an-item-gets-an-empty-field

Still getting absolutely random empty responses. :(
I'm not sure what to try next. Pity!!